# DynamoDB Model Chronological Shipment Update Data

Tags: nosql, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-dynamodb-data-modeling

I recently just started learning about DynamoDB single table design. Now, I am trying to model Shipment Update data that has the following properties:

- an account has multiple users
- an account has multiple shipments
- a shipment can change eta multiple times
- each time there's a shipment update, a new record will be inserted

Access patterns:

1. get all shipments of an account displaying the last updated status ordered by eta in an ascending order
2. for a given shipment, get the chronological updates

[image]

[image]

I am having a difficulty trying to resolve the 2 access patterns mentioned above. If, per se, I only have 1 record per shipment, then I can just update the sort key for the shipment update items to be `shpm#55abc` and the retrieval of all shipments for a given account by eta is straight forward, which is via the gsi `accountEta`.

How do I resolve this to get the access patterns I need? Should I consider having a separate table for the shipment update audit, i.e. to store just the shipment updates? So that when I need access pattern #2, then I query this audit table by the shipment id to get all the chronological updates. But, I feel like this defeats the purpose of the single table design.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A single-table design is a good fit for these access patterns.  Use overloadable, [generic key names](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/bp-modeling-nosql-B.html) like PK and SK.  Here is one approach<sup>*</sup>:

Shipments have a "current" record.  Add a global secondary index (`GSI1`) to create an alternate Primary Key for querying by account in ETA order (pattern #1).  All changes to the shipment are executed as updates to this "current" record.

```yaml
# shipment "current" record
PK             SK                                 GSI1PK            GSI1SK
shpmt#55abc    x_current                          account#123       x_eta#2022-07-01
```

Next, enable [DynamoDB Streams](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/streamsmain.html) on the table to capture shipment changes.  Each time a "current" record is updated, the Lambda backing the Stream writes the `OLD_IMAGE` to the table as a [change control record](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/implementing-version-control-using-amazon-dynamodb/).  This enables pattern #2 by shipment and account.

```yaml
# shipment update record
PK             SK                                 GSI1PK           GSI1SK
shpmt#55abc    update#2022-06-28T06:10:33.247Z    account#123      update#2022-06-28T06:10:33.247Z
```

One virtue of this approach is that a single query operation can retrieve both the current shipment record and its full/partial change history in reverse order.  This is the reason for the `x_` prefixes on the current record's keys. A query with a key expression of `PK = shpmt#55abc AND SK >= "update"`, DESC sorting with `ScanIndexForward=False` and a limit of 2 returns the current record (`x_current`) and the latest update record.

*  Whether this is a good solution for you also [depends on](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/bp-general-nosql-design.html#bp-general-nosql-design-approach) expected read/write volumes.

Comment: hey thanks @fedonev. i am still digesting this, so bear with me before accepting your answer. on your code blocks `# shipment "current" record`, the gsi has the same name `GSI1SK`. was it meant to be `GSI1PK` and `GSI1SK`? And on your `GSI1SK`, 1 is prefixed with `x_eta` and the other `update`. what is the reason for that?

I need to read up on the DynamoDB Streams, haven't explored that previously.

Comment: @billydh Index values: yes, deliberate.  It's the [GSI overloading](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/bp-gsi-overloading.html) pattern - one index holds several record types.  Index attribute name: right, typo is now fixed!

Comment: N.B. [Alex Debrie's book](https://www.dynamodbbook.com) is a great way to learn DynamoDB's idioms.

Comment: On my question section, I didn't have the `accountId` column, which, in your solution, it looks like it is used as the `GSI1PK`, so I added a new attribute, `accountId`, where the value can just be `123`. But, I am a bit confused regarding the `GSI1SK`. which attribute does it take its value from?

For the current record, the value is `x_eta#2022-07-01`, where the `SK` is `x_current`, but for the update record `update#2022-06-28T06:10:33.247Z`, which is the same as the `SK`.

Comment: I just realised, are `GSI1PK` and `GSI1SK` attributes?

Comment: @billydh Yes, they are attribute names.  My answer follows a [common attribute naming pattern](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/bp-modeling-nosql-B.html) that uses generic key names and index overloading.

Comment: so with the `GSI1`, when I want to get all shipments for an account, then the query would be `GSI1PK` = `account#123` and `GSI1SK` begins_with `x_eta`, right?

Comment: @billydh Right!

Comment: with this table design, it means most of the attributes should be made nullable, is that right?